# expr: non-integer argument | Windows 10 Bash

Tags: bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux

```
#!/bin/bash
#Variable to store total word count
words=$(wc $1 | awk '{print $2}')
count=$(grep -c "$2" "$1")
echo "Word Count:" $words
echo "Instance count of "$2": "$count
percentage=$(expr $count / $words)
echo $percentage
```

My machine is running on Windows 10, this is my code, the script takes two arguments - a text file and a word.

`words` stores the total number of words from the text file,
while `count` stores the instances of the word parameter in the text file.

`echo $words` returns `4` and `echo $count` returns `1` so why do I get the error: `expr: non-integer argument`

Comment: Your file has DOS line endings, and `words` and `counts` both actually end with carriage returns. The output of `echo "$words xxxxxxxxxx"`, for example, should be illuminating.

Comment: `declare -p words` would show that something is off, though not as clearly as it should. If you are using `bash` 4.4 or later, `echo "${words@Q}"` will clearly show the carriage return in the value.